# How to retrieve an unit's initialization and finalization address?

Tags: delphi

We may use operator `@IntToStr` to return address of function `IntToStr`.  Is there any ways to retrieve an unit's initialization and finalization's address?

Comment: I know there's a `procedure InitUnits` Delphi's internal `System.pas` but I don't know if the InitContext data is publicly accessible.

Comment: The initialization/finalization code is defined at compile time. One way to interact is via the `ExitProc` pointer. By chaining this pointer, which gets executed when the program exits, you can control what's happening during the programs termination. Typically the chain is defined in the units initialization phase. By manipulating the stored pointers, it is possible to interact with the finalization phase at runtime.

Comment: If you would explain for what you need this, it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Simple answer, no. What would you do with the information anyway?

Comment: If you want to have the addresses so you can call them at other times, then simply make two procedures, e.g. `Init`and `Finish`, call these during initialization and finalization respectively and then you can call them at any other time too. But I doubt it is a good idea to do so. If you want the addresses of *other* units, you're totally out of luck.

Comment: There is a global, but not publicly accessible variable InitContext in the System unit which contains that information. Unfortunately there seems to be no way to access it. So, the answer remains: No.